# JQuery/JS Giving different results between browsers and between refresh types

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh

I have a small Javascript/JQuery function that gets the height of content on the page, and then sets the height of a center div to match. If the content isn't as long as the page displays, then it extends the div beyond the content to make sure that the center div reaches all the way down to the footer.

The problem is, it seems to be acting differently in different browsers and depending on the refresh type, and for the life of me, I can't figure out why.

First off, here is the code:

```
<script>
    //sets a minimum height
    var minHeight = 200;

    var resizeContent = function(){
        //gets the height of the page as a whole, then takes off a little for the header and footer
        var h = $('body').height() - $('#footer').height() - $('#header').height();
        //gets the height of content in the wrapper div, which is directly inside the center div
        var h2 = $('#wrapper').height() + 30;
        //gets the height of the 2 sidebar divs
        var h3 = $('#left').height();
        var h4 = $('#right').height();

        //compares them all to take the highest one
        h = h > minHeight ? h : minHeight;
        h = h > h2 ? h : h2;
        h = h > h3 ? h : h3;
        h = h > h4 ? h : h4;

        //sets the height of the center div
        $('#content').height(h);
    }

    //calls on page load and resize
    $(document).ready(resizeContent);
    $(window).resize(resizeContent);
</script>
```

Now what it is doing is the following.

Internet Explorer
Regular Page Load - Works fine
Regular Refresh - Works fine
Shift Refresh - Works fine

Firefox
Regular Page Load - Works fine
Regular Refresh - Works fine
Shift Refresh - The content div is shorter than it should be

Chrome
Regular Page Load - The content div is shorter than it should be
Regular Refresh - The content div is shorter than it should be
Shift Refresh - Works fine

Anyone have any ideas on what could be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many cases you will need to call such methods onLoad.

```
$(window).load(function(){
  resizeContent();
});
```

This is because the size of an image is unknown when document ready is called unless you assigned it in the attributes. If you don´t the image gets resized as soon its loaded which affects the content as well. So unexpected heights can be the result in your function.